# SQL Server - update schema of one db from another

Tags: sql-server-2008, scripting

I have two databses on a SQL Server -- one for development (call it "TestData"), and one for production (call it "LiveData").  I make changes to TestData -- typically adding tables or adding new fields to existing tables (rarely dropping anything) and creating **or modifying** Stored Procedures.  At some point, I would like to update the LiveData tables, stored procedures, etc. with the changes made to TestData.  I only want this to affect the schema, not the actual data.  What is the best way to do this?  I am new to SQL Server, so the more detailed the explanation, the better.

edit:  I know there are third-party programs out there, but I'm looking into ways to do this without a separate software, just using scripts, etc.

Comment: do not cross post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/96f38b23-d591-45d8-b3ea-a798d95b0430?prof=required

Comment: i'm sorry if that is considered poor ettiquette. I was not aware. However, why not? I wasn't getting the answer I was looking for here, and the forum I posted to on MSDN is a SQL Server-specific forum, so I was hoping for different answers, which I did get in the end. So I would appreciate if you could explain what is considered wrong with "cross posting". Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [redgate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/).

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for in an answer, but I'll accept it anyhow

Answer (score 1):

[DBComparer](http://www.dbcomparer.com/) is a great free utility to compare schemas. It is a little buggy and crashes sometimes, but other than that it works great.